# show that $m^*(E)>0$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If the set $E \subset \mathbb{R} $ contains at least one interior point, show that $m^*(E)>0$, where $m^*$ is the outer Lebesgue measure.

---

Let $x$ be the interior point, then $B(x,r) \subset E$ (1) for some $r>0$. In $\mathbb{R}$ if we fix $r$ then  $B(x,r)=(a,b)$ with $b>a$, for some $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and now we know that $m^*(a,b)=b-a>0$
which we conclude that $m^*(E)>0$ because from (1) we get $m^*(a,b)<m^*(E)$

I am new to measure theory and I started with some easy and basic exercises, is my solution ok?

Comment: Cite the (previously proved?) property: if $A \subseteq B$, then $m^*(A) \le m^*(B)$.  If that was not already proved, then your proof here is no good.

Comment: @GEdgar this has been proven in my notes and I can use it to solve exercises

Comment: OK, put in into your proof.  DO NOT expect the reader to know it already.  Even if the reader is only your instructor, you have to show that YOU know it.

Comment: @GEdgar you are right, I should have included that in my solution, sorry for been lazy. And thanks for answering.